# Undefined method Rails error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am a Rails noob and not sure what is causing the Undefined method error. Here's my code:

#### routes.rb

```
namespace :dashboard do
  resources :subjects
end
```

#### new.html.rb

```
<%= form_for(@subject) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

#### subjects_controller.rb

```
module Dashboard
  class SubjectsController < ApplicationController

    def new
      @subject = Subject.new
    end
  end
end
```

When I load /dashboard/subjects/new in the browser, I get the following error on the form_for(@subject) line

```
undefined method `subjects_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f951e0f2b38>:0x007f951e0f18f0>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work since you are having namespaced resource

```
<%= form_for([:dashboard, @subject]) do |f| %>
```